# Need to change terms and conditions html, used a plugin, but is not working

Tags: magento2, plugin, terms-and-conditions

I need to change the Terms and Conditions HTML. The client wants to add HTML in the middle of the text. For that I need to change the  `getAgreementsConfig` function (`Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\AgreementsConfigProvider`).

I build a plugin to change the result of this function. I worked on this for the last 2 days, and no result until now. I don't know what else to do.
My code is:
My `di.xml` file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\AgreementsConfigProvider">
      <plugin name="agreementsHtmlText" type="VendorName\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Plugin\AgreementPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And my Plugin is (`VendorName\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Plugin\AgreementPlugin`):

```
<?php

namespace VenderName\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\Api\SearchCriteria\ActiveStoreAgreementsFilter;

class AgreementPlugin
{

    public function afterGetAgreementsConfig(\Magento\CheckoutAgreements\Model\AgreementsConfigProvider $subject, $result){

        foreach ($result['agreements'] as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key]['checkboxText'] ='ahahahhah'; // test if result changes
        }


        return 'qiweoqiwueioqwiueioquw'; //just to test if it changes the resukt
    }
}
```

I tried and change almost everything, and until now, no luck. Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: It will not work because the method `getAgreementsConfig` is a protected method. Plugins only work on public methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to plug in to the public function of this class:

```
public function getConfig()
{
    $agreements = [];
    $agreements['checkoutAgreements'] = $this->getAgreementsConfig();

    return $agreements;
}
```

Therefore, "afterGetConfig" should be working.

Edit:

What you probably want to do is allow links again in the "checkboxText". This will not work with a simple plugin, since you need to access some protected variable of the class to get the data before rendering the agreements array.
Instead override the class with a preference:

```
class CustomAgreementsConfigProvider extends AgreementsConfigProvider 
   implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
  protected function getAgreementsConfig()
  {
    $agreementConfiguration = [];
    $isAgreementsEnabled = $this->scopeConfiguration->isSetFlag(
        AgreementsProvider::PATH_ENABLED,
        ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );

    $agreementsList = $this->checkoutAgreementsRepository->getList();
    $agreementConfiguration['isEnabled'] = (bool) ($isAgreementsEnabled && count($agreementsList) > 0);

    foreach ($agreementsList as $agreement) {
        $agreementConfiguration['agreements'][] = [
            'content' => $agreement->getIsHtml()
                ? $agreement->getContent()
                : nl2br($this->escaper->escapeHtml($agreement->getContent())),
            'checkboxText' => $agreement->getCheckboxText(), // TODO: this is usually escaped
            'mode' => $agreement->getMode(),
            'agreementId' => $agreement->getAgreementId()
        ];
    }

    return $agreementConfiguration;
}
```

}